# Is there a Stack Exchange for reading/books?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for book-specific questions (*e.g.*, how does Harry Potter open the snitch in the 7th book)? Is/Should there be a community for this?

Comment: Though, the dupe doesn't recommend SF&F.SE as a solution because it doesn't specifically ask about Harry Potter. As such, the duplicate may be inappropriate.

Comment: I think the asker has used *i.e.* when really they mean *e.g.* instead. This is really a duplicate - the example happens to be on-topic at a second site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are actually two sites you could consider using.

The first is called [Literature.SE](http://literature.stackexchange.com/). It's for talking about literature. They're happy to answer questions about books.

> Literature Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for scholars and enthusiasts of literature. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about literature.

Also, because your question is about a science fiction or fantasy series, it would also be on topic on our [Science Fiction and Fantasy site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of Potter questions on [scifi.se].

Comment: For book recommendation questions, there's also a ["reference-request"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D) tag.

Comment: Anything about tech-books? science, programming, math, astronomy, etc.